# SQL Results Set from List into grid

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, list, grid, resultset

I have two tables of data that I've joined.

```
Student 
UPN | Name
```

and

```
Subject
UPN | Subject | Result
```

I have written the following query to bring out a list of all values.

```
SELECT student.upn,
       subject,
       result
FROM   student
       JOIN subject
         ON subject.upn = student.upn
```

This results in the following

```
UPN             Subject       Result
8152760         English       3c
8138130         Spanish       2b
8152760         Spanish       3c
8128500         English       3c
8152760         Mathematics   2b
8152760         French        2b
```

What I would like to do is have the resultset display for each distinct student a column for each subject, so something like this:

```
UPN             English      French      Mathematics      Spanish
8152760         3c           2b          2b               3c
8138130         NULL         NULL        NULL             2b
8128500         3c           NULL        NULL             NULL
```

Ideally I'd like it to auto generate the columns from my subject names, but I'm happy to hardcode them if this is more straightforward.

Comment: @rudym thanks for your help. Although where's your comment gone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
declare @t as table (UPN int, Subject varchar(50), Result varchar(3))
insert into @t values(8152760, 'English'     ,  '3c')
insert into @t values(8138130, 'Spanish'     ,  '2b')
insert into @t values(8152760, 'Spanish'     ,  '3c')
insert into @t values(8128500, 'English'     ,  '3c')
insert into @t values(8152760, 'Mathematics' ,  '2b')
insert into @t values(8152760, 'French'      ,  '2b')



select distinct t.upn, 
e.Result as Enlish,
s.Result as Spanish,
f.Result as French,
m.Result as Mathematics
from @t t
left join @t e on e.UPN = t.upn and e.Subject = 'English'
left join @t s on s.UPN = t.upn and s.Subject = 'Spanish'
left join @t f on f.UPN = t.upn and f.Subject = 'French'
left join @t m on m.UPN = t.upn and m.Subject = 'Mathematics'
```

`PIVOT` version works only with aggregation, that is why I deleted my comment )

```
SELECT UPN, 
[English]        ,
[Spanish]        ,                       
[Mathematics]    ,
[French]
FROM
(SELECT UPN, Subject, Result 
    FROM @t) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
count(Result)
FOR Subject IN ([English]        ,
                [Spanish]        ,                       
                [Mathematics]    ,
                [French])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: This is great @rudym. The only problem is my resultset isn't limited to the values specified in the example. Is it possible to change the insert from specific values into column name references?

Comment: You can build dynamically the execution string and execute it. Like `Declare @sql1 varchar(max)
Declare @sql2 varchar(max)

Select @sql1 = 'long string'
Select @sql2 = 'long string part 2'

exec (@sql1 + @sql2)`